# Show that $A\cap B = \{0\} \;\;\;\text{and}\;\;\; A+B\;\text{closed} \implies\|a\| + \|b\| \leq \|a+b\|$

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

This is the problem I am working on, the actual question is in bold:

Let $(X,\|\cdot\|)$ be Banach and $A,B\subset X$ closed subspaces such that $A\cap B = \{0\}$. Consider, $$A+B:=\{a+b : a\in A, b\in B\} \quad \text{with norm} \quad \|\cdot\|_d: a+b \to \|a\|+\|b\|$$
as subspace of $X$.

Prove that $A+B$ is closed if and only if  $\|\cdot\|$ is equivalent to $\|\cdot\|_d$ on $A+B$.

---

My attempt, we know immediately that $A,B$ are Banach. Suppose $A+B$ is closed. Let $a+b\in A+B$. Then,
$$\|a+b\| \leq \|a\| + \|b\| = \|a+b\|_d$$

now my problem is, I don't know how to do this next part,
$$A\cap B = \{0\} \;\;\;\text{and}\;\;\; A+B\;\text{closed} \implies\|a\| + \|b\| \leq \|a+b\|$$
**I am not sure how to proceed with this. Obviously $A$ and $B$ are linearly independent but we are working with infinite dimensions. Ideally I would like a proof that does not involve decomposition into basis vectors.**

To prove the other direction, suppose the norms are equivalent on $A+B$, then, let $x\in X$ be a limit point of $A+B$, i.e. we have $(a_n+b_n)_n \subset A+B$ approaching $x$ with respect to $\|\cdot\|$. But $a_n\to a\in A$ and $b_n\to b\in B$. It remains to prove that $x=a+b$
$$\|x - (a+b)\| = \lim_{n \to \infty}\|(a_n+b_n) - (a + b)\| \leq 
\lim_{n \to \infty}C\|a_n - a\|
+ 
\lim_{n \to \infty}C\|b_n - b\| 
\to 0$$
by equivalence of norms.

Comment: What are $Y$ and $Z$?

Comment: Sorry meant to write $A+B$

Comment: Define linear projection operators from $A+B$ onto $A$ and $B$, and find their norms.

Comment: I doubt you can prove $A+B$ closed implies $\|a\| + \|b\| \leq \|a+b\|$.  Not even in $\mathbb R^2$ with the usual norm.  More likely you will prove: there exists a constant $C$ with $\|a\| + \|b\| \leq C \|a+b\|$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a useful corollary to the open mapping theorem (see Rudin, "Functional Analysis", 2nd ed, Corollary 2.12 (c)) which (in this case) states that
if $\Lambda: W \to Z$ is continuous, linear, bijective then there exist $r_1,r_2>0$ such that $r_1 \| w \| \le \|\Lambda w\| \le r_2 \|w\|$. (Symbols changed to protect the innocent.)

In the following, let $\Lambda: A \times B \to A+B$ defined by $\Lambda((a,b)) = a+b$, with the norm $(a,b) \mapsto \|a\|+\|b\|$ on $A \times B$.

Suppose $A,B, A+B$ are closed, then we see that $A\times B$ and $A+B$ are Banach spaces and $\Lambda$ satisfies the relevant conditions. Hence there are $r_1,r_2$ such that
$r_1 \|a+b\| \le \|\Lambda ((a,b))\| = \|a\|+\|b\| \le r_2 \|a+b\|$.

Comment: Thanks, this must be the right intended approach. Turns out I already have all these results proven in the notes, but I just forgot about them cause I have never used them since.